# Error occurs when adding inheritance to domain: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the nature of the problem I've been having.  I have two `Domain Classes` for my grails app: `HeadOfHousehold` and `Dependent`.  They are nearly identical, except in a couple of places; firstly, `HeadOfHousehold` owns `Dependent` using the construct: `static hasMany = [dependents: Dependent]`, and `Dependent` has `static belongsTo = [headOfHousehold: HeadOfHousehold]`, secondly `Dependent` has the property `String type` which can be either `Spouse` or `Dependent` while `HeadOfHousehold` has a `transient` method `getType()` which simply returns `Self`, and lastly there are two properties `currentAddress` and `previousAddress` which are also `Domain object`s which are contained in `HeadOfHousehold`, while any `Dependent` points back to the `HeadOfHousehold`'s addresses.  Now I was having trouble doing any sort of query which would use more than one aspect of the `Current Address` on the `Dependent` so I decided to combine these objects through inheritance so I could just query vs the parent class of the two, and get results from both `HeadOfHousehold` and `Dependent`.

So I combined them in the following way:
`Parent Class` `Person`

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String middleName
    String suffix
    Date dateOfBirth
    Date dateAdded
    String driversLicenseNumber
    String driversLicenseState
    String ssn
    String gender
    Address currentAddress
    Address previousAddress
    MVR mvr
    CreditReport creditReport
    ClueAuto clueAuto
    ClueProperty clueProperty

    static transients =['reportDOB','reportDlNumberState','firstLastMiddleSuffix',
                    'reportAddressString']
    static constraints = {
            middleName blank: false, nullable: true
            suffix blank: true, nullable: true
        ssn matches: "[0-9]{9}"
        gender blank: true, nullable: true, matches: "M|F"
        currentAddress nullable: true
        previousAddress blank: true, nullable: true
        mvr nullable: true
        creditReport nullable: true
        clueAuto nullable: true
        clueProperty nullable: true
        dateAdded nullable: true
    }

    public String toString(){
        String returnValue = lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleName
        return returnValue.replaceAll("null"," ")
    }


    //   I'm not sure if this is correct place for these, but they deal with
    // the transformation necessary to create the order object to send it
    // off to the broker in a byte[].
    def getReportDOB(){//dealing with dates is stupid in java X_X
            if(dateOfBirth){
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar()
            calendar.setTime(dateOfBirth)
            return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar)
        }
    }

    def getReportDlNumberState(){
        return driversLicenseNumber +"_" + driversLicenseState
    }

    def getFirstLastMiddleSuffix(){
        return (firstName+"_"+lastName+"_"+middleName+"_"+suffix).replaceAll("null","")
    }

    def getReportAddressString(){
        if(!previousAddress.isEmpty()){
        return "0_HOME,1_BUSINESS"
        } else{
                return "0_HOME"
            }
    }

    //TODO This really shouldn't be necessary I need to figure out why it is.
        def convertGender(){
        switch(gender){
            case "M":
                return "M"
            case "F":
                return "F"
            default:
                return null
        }
        }
    }
```

`Child Class` `Dependent`

```
class Dependent extends Person{
String type //relationship to head of household.


static belongsTo = [headOfHousehold: HeadOfHousehold]

static constraints = {

}

public String toString(){
    String returnValue = lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleName
    return returnValue.replaceAll("null","")
}

def beforeInsert(){
    currentAddress = headOfHousehold.currentAddress
    previousAddress = headOfHousehold.previousAddress
    dateAdded = new Date()
}
```

}

`Child Class` `HeadOfHousehold`

```
class HeadOfHousehold extends Person{



static hasMany = [dependents: Dependent]
static transients =['type']

static mapping = {

}

static constraints = {


}

def getType(){
    return "Self"
}


}
```

Now, this works great, except I had major problems instantiating the objects.  I kept getting an error:

```
Message: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ....clients.Address
```

Which I resolved by adding addresses directly to the constructor, and then saving the addresses immediately afterwards
Thusly:

```
Address currentAddress = FactoryHelperPicardAndPike.createCurrentAddress()
  Address previousAddress = FactoryHelperPicardAndPike.createPreviousAddress()
  HeadOfHousehold hh = FactoryHelperPicardAndPike.createPicard(picardAdded, picardBirthDate, currentAddress, previousAddress)
  saveIt(currentAddress)
  saveIt(previousAddress)
  saveIt(hh)
```

Instead of:

```
HeadOfHousehold hh2 = FactoryHelperPicardAndPike.createPike(pikeAdded, picardBirthDate) 
  Address currentAddress2 = FactoryHelperPicardAndPike.createPikeCurrentAddress() 
  Address previousAddress2 = FactoryHelperPicardAndPike.createPikePreviousAddress() 

  hh2.setCurrentAddress(currentAddress2)
  hh2.setPreviousAddress(previousAddress2)
  saveIt(currentAddress2)
  saveIt(previousAddress2)
  saveIt(hh2)
```

I don't understand exactly what the problem is; and why it only appeared after I added inheritance. I was only able to resolve it via trial and error, which isn't exactly helpful when I run into the problem in the future.  Now I've read all the questions that I could find referring to `unsaved transient instance`, and the best I can figure is the error indicates that my `Address` object is considered a transient until it is saved, and for some reason it won't cascade save with the `HeadOfHousehold` or `Dependent`.  I don't understand how it is different for a inherited object vs a stand alone object.  So can anyone explain why it is I'm getting the error with inherited objects, and not the other way?  Furthermore is an in depth explanation of the error somewhere?  I've read [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne), and it isn't exactly illuminating to me.

I know this is long, and I do appreciate your attention.